Getting the Data pathway automatically drawn in a .PNG
I have a complex list of folders and sub folders on my computer, running windows.
I want to know if there is a way to generate a drawing of the full organization of folders and sub folders, like a tree of folders.
If the solution imply coding,i am familiar with R.
Google didn't help much.
